# KeyPressEvent no detecta la tecla 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, keypressevent

Estoy tratando de capturar las teclas que presiono dentro de un `QLineEdit`, pero el método `keyPressEvent()` no me devuelve ningún resultado cuando presiono algún numero o letra solo parece reaccionar con `key_Return`:

Este es el código de muestra:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QLineEdit
from PyQt5 import Qt, QtCore


class Principal(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.line = QLineEdit(self)

    def keyPressEvent(self,event):
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_0: **# No detecta la tecla 0**
            print("pressed_0")
        elif event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Return:
            print("pressed_return")
        event.accept()


app = QApplication([])
p = Principal()
p.show()
p.resize(600,400)
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Puedes intentar depurar el problema, imprimiendo el valor de `event.key()`, a ver qué recibes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas intentando capturar el evento desde la instancia de tu ventana principal, pero éste no llega a propagarse nunca, es "consumido" por el `QLineEdit`. Si quieres capturar las teclas cuando son pulsadas dentro del `QLineEdit` puedes usar [`QObject.eventFilter`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#eventFilter):

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QLineEdit
from PyQt5 import Qt, QtCore


class Principal(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Principal, self).__init__()

        self.line = QLineEdit(self)
        self.line.installEventFilter(self)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress and obj is self.line:
            if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_0:
                print("pressed_0")
            elif event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Return:
                print("pressed_return") 
        return super(Principal, self).eventFilter(obj, event)



app = QApplication([])
p = Principal()
p.show()
p.resize(600,400)
app.exec_()
```

`return super(Principal, self).eventFilter(obj, event)` permite propagar el evento al padre, si quisieras que ese evento no se propague (por ejemplo detectar el evento al pulsar la tecla <kbd>0</kbd> pero que este no se propague, por lo que el 0 no será ingresado en el `QLineEdit`) debes retornar `True` desde el método `eventFilter` cuando el evento sea capturado:

```
if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_0:
    print("pressed_0")
    return True
```